# c# Spacing alignment on textfile

Tags: c#

based on the image on below, I would like to have proper and consistent alignment and spacing like the right side of image.

Below is my source code for the first output, please help thanks

```
        string line = null;
        string printout = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(line);

        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            StreamReader file = null;
            file = new StreamReader(filePath);
            try
            {

                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line == string.Empty)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (!line.StartsWith("-"))
                    {
                        if ((line.Length <= 82) || line.Contains("MY01"))
                        {
                            printout = String.Format(line.Remove(0, 5).ToUpper());
                            var result = Regex.Replace(printout, "[\t ][ ]{10}", " ");
                            Console.WriteLine(result);
                        }                    
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("not valid", e.Message);
            }

            finally
            {
                if (file != null)
                    file.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using [`PadRight`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padright?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: tried but cant :x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to see exactly what your original file format looks like, but here's one way to do it using `string.PadRight` to pad each column item to the correct width for that column.

If we pretend we have an input file like the one on the left, this method will format it to something similar to the one on the right.

This probably isn't the most efficient way to do this, but what it does is:

1. Read all the lines of the file, and for each line, split it on whitespace characters into an array of "items".
2. Finds the maximum width of each column and saves it in a dictionary with the column index as a key and the column width as a value
3. Writes each line back to the file after first setting the width of each line item to the correct width for that column

```cs
public static void FormatTextColumns(string filePath)
{
    // Minimum number of spaces between two columns
    var minColSpace = 3;

    // Dictionary holds the index and max width of each column
    var columnWidths = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    // Read each file line into an array of items by splitting the line on whitespace
    var lineItems = File
        .ReadAllLines(filePath)
        .Select(line => line.Split(new char[0], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        .ToList();

    // Get the max column count
    var maxColumns = lineItems.Max(x => x.Length);

    // Save the max width of each column
    for (var i = 0; i < maxColumns; i++)
    {
        foreach (var line in lineItems)
        {
            if (line.Length > i)
            {
                int existingValue;
                columnWidths.TryGetValue(i, out existingValue);
                columnWidths[i] = Math.Max(line[i].Length, existingValue);
            }
        }
    }

    // Save each line back to the file after padding each column item to the correct length
    File.WriteAllLines(filePath, lineItems.Select(line =>
        string.Concat(line.Select((item, index) =>
            item.PadRight(columnWidths[index] + minColSpace)))));
}
```

Sample file input:

```xml
CISCO  ZPRPflubadub     08-0729-01-MARch   08-0729-01   1   EA
CISCO  ZPRP 08-0729-01-MAR   08-0729-0134   1   EA
CISCO     ZPRP 08-0729-01-MAR   08-0729-01   1   EA
CISCO  ZPRP 08-0729-01-MAR   08-0729-01   10        EA  4
CISCOar  ZPRP 08-0729-01-MAR   08-0729-01   1   EA
CISCO  ZPRP 08-0729-01-MARffe        08-0729-01   1   EA
```

Sample file output:

```xml
CISCO     ZPRPflubadub   08-0729-01-MARch    08-0729-01     1    EA   
CISCO     ZPRP           08-0729-01-MAR      08-0729-0134   1    EA   
CISCO     ZPRP           08-0729-01-MAR      08-0729-01     1    EA   
CISCO     ZPRP           08-0729-01-MAR      08-0729-01     10   EA   4   
CISCOar   ZPRP           08-0729-01-MAR      08-0729-01     1    EA   
CISCO     ZPRP           08-0729-01-MARffe   08-0729-01     1    EA
```

Comment: I have tested the code and it able to run expected result, but when there is a missing field for respective column, the other columns will fill inside missing columns

Comment: like when "08-0729-01" from the first row is missing, then "1" from the first row as well will be replaced on that missing column fields.